# nodejs is throwing symbol lookup error

Tags: node.js

This is the first time I am getting this error using nodejs, not sure what is it and how to come out of it. Below is the error:

```
node: symbol lookup error: /home/zishan/node_modules/zmq/build/Release/zmq.node: undefined symbol: zmq_sendmsg
```

when I am getting above error:
I have two test scripts testServer.js and testClient.js, when I am running testServer.js it's working fine but when I am running testClient.js by node testClient.js than testServer.js node window immediately throws above error.

below is the code for both scripts.

```
// testServer.js

var zmq = require('zmq');
var socket = zmq.socket('push');

socket.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
console.log('Server is open on port 3000');

setInterval(function(){
  console.log('sending work');
  socket.send('some work');
}, 500);
```

Below is testClient.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq')
var socket = zmq.socket('pull');

socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
console.log('client connected to port 3000');

socket.on('message', function(msg){
  console.log(msg.toString());
});
```

My Env.

- Ubuntu - 13.04
- Nodejs - 0.10.24

Recently i reinstalled node using [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) because i got hit by this error node-gyp rebuild.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How have you installed zmq? With `npm`? Didn't you get any error while building `zmq`?

Comment: yes zmq was installed however just to remove any possibility I just reinstalled it again. and it installed without any error. I am out of clue as to why this error.

Comment: Try and see if it is just zmq that is the problem. Is it build-passing? Does your node app work if you remove it? For someone *just* starting with Node.js, do you have to use zmq?

Comment: dc2 - yes it's zmq only which is troubling, node example is working. any ways, your statement is right but assumption is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try uninstalling latest zmq module by `npm uninstall zmq` and try with specific version of zmq `npm install zmq@2.4.0`